# error backup table/create table use procedure and codeigniter

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, plsql

I'm trying to backup my current table use stored procedure on oracle and codeigniter.

this is my procedure :

```
CREATE OR  PROCEDURE PROC_BACKUP_DATA1 (p_tablename  VARCHAR2, out_message 
OUT VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
execute immediate 'create table ROADMAP_'|| to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMddHH24miss') || 'as Select * from ' || p_tablename||'';
commit;
out_message := 'Data berhasil di backup';                               
exception
when others then
rollback;
out_message := sqlerrm;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(out_message);
END;
```

this is my CI model  code :

```
public function fbackup(){
$p_tablename="ZZZ_REKAP_ROADMAP";
$stid=oci_parse($this->db->conn_id, 'begin PROC_BACKUP_DATA1(:p_tablename, :out_message); end;');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':p_tablename', $p_tablename);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':out_message', $out_message, 40);
oci_execute($stid);
print"$out_message\n";
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($this->db->conn_id);
}
```

this is my CI controller :

```
public function backup(){
$this->RoadmapModel->fbackup();
$this->load->view('index');
}
```

and also this is the error messages :

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

i've try as i can, and stack
any body have a solution?

Thanks broo....

Comment: You're missing a space before `as` in the `|| 'as Select * from '` part. (In general, if you have a problem with dynamic SQL, print out the constructed string you're trying to run - it's often pretty obvious then what the mistake is, especially for things like missing spaces...) Also, the commit and rollback are pointless as DDL commits automatically; and it's usually much better to just let an exception bubble up to the caller, rather than using `when others`. Only catch exceptions you need to explicitly need to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `Procedure` syntax has missing `replace` after `OR`. See here:

> CREATE OR  PROCEDURE PROC_BACKUP_DATA1 (p_tablename  VARCHAR2,
>   out_message

See below working version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_BACKUP_DATA1 (
     P_TABLENAME         VARCHAR2,
     OUT_MESSAGE   OUT   VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'create table ROADMAP_'
                       || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'yyyyMMddHH24miss')
                       || ' as Select * from '
                       || P_TABLENAME
                       || '';

     OUT_MESSAGE := 'Data berhasil di backup';
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
          ROLLBACK;
          OUT_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (OUT_MESSAGE);
END;
```

Also note what @Alex said regarding exception handling. Simply putting `dbms_output` wound not handle the `exception` and procedure will execute `successfully` even incase of error.

Comment: thanks for the answer XING and Alex for the solution, i'll try to edit my procedure, but is there any something wrong in my CI code??

Comment: thanks again for XING and Alex... i replace my own procedure with  the above procedure and its worked, thanks brooo